# How to append multiple data variables on jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
myapi.selectUsers(function (users) {
        users.forEach(function (user) {
            typeof user.username;
            typeof user.age;
        });
});
```

android logcat:

```
("{\"data\":{\"userDataList\":[{\"username\":\"miamitheuser\",\"age\":\"25\"},{\"username\":\"myuserisnone\",\"age\":\"23\"}]},\"status\":200}")
```

If it was a single varible, I would use this:

```
$('body').append(user.age);
```

How do I append multiple variables?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `$('body').data('age', user.age);` to save data and `$('body').data('age');` to retrieve it.